# Can you list only opaque Google Calendar events

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to retrieve events from a google calendar (using Java but I haven't found a way to do it with REST requests either).

I want to only get events that are busy (on google events, this means the `transparency` field is marked as `opaque`

Is there any way to do this?

I've tried using the `q` parameter set to `opaque` which should match any field according do the documentation, to no avail.

Here's the way I'm currently retrieving these events:

```
return calendar.events()
          .list(calendarId)
          .setTimeMin(new DateTime(from))
          .setTimeMax(new DateTime(to))
          .setOrderBy("startTime")
          .execute()
          .getItems();
```

Comment: Please, share the payload and its callback so I can help you better.

Comment: To further expand my former comment: Your approach is correct, you should specify the attribute and its value on the payload, please share the payload so we can take a look and the callback that you get so I can help you better.